# Mysql seconds_behind master very high

Tags: mysql-5.7

Hi we have mysql master slave replication, master is mysql 5.6 and slave is mysql 5.7, seconds behind master is 245000, how I make it catch up faster. Right now it is taking more than 6 hours to copy 100 000 seconds.

My slave ram is 128 GB. Below is my my.cnf

```
    [mysqld]

    # Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
    # cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 110G

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir         = /usr/local/mysql
datadir         = /disk1/mysqldata
port = 3306
#server_id = 3
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
user=mysql
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
join_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

#copied from old config
#key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 256M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_limit       = 1M
#disabling query_cache_size  and type, for replication purpose, need to enable it when going live
query_cache_size        = 0
#query_cache_size        = 64M
#query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_type = OFF
#GroupBy
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
enforce-gtid-consistency
gtid-mode = ON
log_slave_updates=0
slave_transaction_retries   = 100
#replication related changes
server-id               = 2
relay-log               = /disk1/mysqllog/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin                 = /disk1/mysqllog/binlog/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db            = brandmanagement
#replicate_wild_do_table=brandmanagement.%
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_gnip\_data\_recent
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_gnip\_data
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_fb\_rt\_data
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_keyword\_tweets
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_gnip\_data\_old
replicate-wild-ignore-table=brandmanagement.t\_gnip\_data\_new
binlog_format=row
report-host=10.125.133.220
report-port=3306
#sync-master-info=1
read-only=1
net_read_timeout = 7200
net_write_timeout = 7200
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
sync_binlog=0
sync_relay_log_info=0
max_relay_log_size=268435456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of possible solutions. But I'll go with the simplest one. Have you got enough network bandwidth to send all changes over the network? You're using "row" binlog, which may be good in case of random, unindexed updates. But if you're changing a lot of data using indexes only, then "mixed" binlog may be better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually we do make lot of updates every day. Our bandwidth is very good. I will make the change to mixed and try once. Any other suggestion based on our my.cnf would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have changed it to mixed, now performance is better. Is there any way I can increase it even more.

Comment: @user2674154 Check what does mysqltuner.pl have to say about your server. Don't blindly trust everything it says, but read up on settings it flags.

Comment: What is mysqltuner.pl how do I see that, can you please explain.

Comment: Thanks, my slave had caught up.